# Is "my problem solved" Correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

we are arguing about whether the sentence "my problem solved" is Correct or not?
If NOT so what's wrong with it?
my friends are saying that the correct form is "my problem got solved" but I'm saying it means something else and I want to know exactly what's wrong whit my own sentence.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "sentence", because it has no "active" verb (only a past participle used adjectivally). But it could occur as a valid ***noun phrase***, in contexts such as ***My problem solved is your problem halved**.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers In my opinion the tense of sentence is past simple. What should I add to it so that it becomes simple past. what is omitted?

Comment: No - it's not helpful to think of ***solved*** there as "Past Simple". Syntactically speaking, it's an ***adjective***, pure and simple. And if your comment implies that you think there's some meaningful distinction between "past simple" and "simple past", you're wrong about that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that "solve" in the way you are trying to use it is a *transitive* verb, in which case you need an *object*. In your "sentence" (see comments) "problem" would act as a *subject*, which is not what you mean: it would instead mean that your problem solved something else. So you either need to use the passive form:

> My problem is solved

or you make a more detailed sentence:

> The latest update solved my problem

Of course you can use the expression "problem solved" with nothing else, which is OK because it actually means "(the) problem (is) solved".

Notice, finally, that "solve" can be both transitive and intransitive. Its intransitive form can be used for instance in maths:

> Solve this equation for X

However, I can only find this in the Merriam-Webster:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solve